# How to execute the second function firstly in chain functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Question as below:
Create a function GoodMan

```
GoodMan("Tom")
```

> output: I am Tom

```
GoodMan("Tom").rest(10).learn("computer")
```

> output: I am Tom
>   //wait 10 seconds
>   Start learning after 10 seconds
>   Learning computer

```
GoodMan("Tom").restFirst(5).learn("english")
```

> output:
>    //wait 5 seconds
>   Start learning after 5 seconds
>   I am Tom
>   Learning english

I have finished the first two questions. However, in the third question, how to execute the restFirst(5) function firstly in chain functions in Javascript?
Should I add a selector to determine whether GoodMan("Tom") execute.

Code shows below:

```js
var GoodMan = function(str){
    var callback_f = new Object;
    str1 = "I am " + str;
    console.log(str1);
    callback_f.rest = function(num){
        sleep(num * 1000);
        console.log ("Start learning after " + num + " seconds");
        return callback_f;
    };
    callback_f.learn = function(str){
        str2 = "Leaning " + str;
        console.log (str2);
    };
    return callback_f;
}

function sleep(ms) {
    var unixtime_ms = new Date().getTime();
    while(new Date().getTime() < unixtime_ms + ms) {}
}

GoodMan("Tom").rest(10).learn("computer");
```

Comment: instead of hard coding the first log add it to the object and call it second in the chain. if not, How do you think the order should be determined ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about having a queue of tasks?

```js
function TaskQueue(tasks) {
       return function createQueue(...args) {
           const queue = [];
           let running = false;

           async function processQueue() {
              if(running) return;
              running = true;

              // console.log(queue);
              for(const { task, args } of queue) await task(...args);
              
              running = false;
           }

           function addTask(task, priority, args) {
               queue[priority ? "unshift" : "push"]({ task, args });
               setTimeout(processQueue);
           }

           const instance = {};
           
           for(const [key, priority, task] of tasks) {
              instance[key] = function(...args) { addTask(task, priority, args); return this; };
           }

           if(instance.constructor) instance.constructor(...args);

           return instance;
       };
    }


    const GoodMan = TaskQueue([
      ["constructor", 0, (name) => console.log(`Hi, ${name}`)],
      ["rest", 0, (time) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, time * 1000))],
      ["restFirst", 1, (time) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, time * 1000))],
      ["learn", 0, subject => console.log(`Learning ${subject}`)]
    ]);

    GoodMan("Tom").restFirst(5).learn("english")
```

Comment: very good answer! big thx! just miss the log "Start learning after 10 seconds" and "Start learning after 5 seconds"

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below:

```
const goodMan = (name) => {
  return Promise.resolve(`I am ${name}`);
};
const restFirst = (time) => {
  return Promise.resolve(`Start learning after ${time} seconds`);
};
const learn = (subject) => {
  return Promise.resolve(`Learning ${subject}`);
};

const allTogether = (async () => {
  const goodManOutput = await goodMan('Tom');
  const restOutput = await restFirst(5);
  const learnOutput = await learn('English');
  return Promise.resolve(`${restOutput} ${goodManOutput} ${learnOutput}`);
});

allTogether().then(newOutput => {
    console.log(newOutput);
});
```

Hope this helps.